# How to change the default code indentation in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode4, indentation

When I created a new view controller, its default code indentation style looks like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Can I change any settings so the default code indentation looks like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 43):

Choose Xcode > Preferences… from the menu bar (default shortcut: command-comma).  Then click the “Text Editing” section.  Then choose the “Indentation” tab.  Set the “Indent width” to 2.

[image: Xcode preferences]

You can change the indentation width for just one project by selecting the project in the Project Navigator, then setting the “Indent“ value in the “Text Settings” section of the File Inspector:

[image]

You can ask Xcode to reformat existing code with the new indentation width by selecting the code and choosing Editor > Structure > Re-Indent from the menu bar (default shortcut: control-i).

Comment: I've try this before, but it doesn't work. When I create a new project or a new .m file, the default indentation remains the same.